# Security checks while using request.GET and request.META for getting various values in django python

Tags: python, django, security, xss

While getting a request parameter using request.GET or using request.META for getting HTTP_REFERER ,What type of Security checks I can implement for extra security in django.

Specifically I am looking for **XSS ( cross site scripting )** security checks for it as One of my collegue has pointed out that some body can do the XSS attack here some how.

**Sample code:**

```
next = request.GET.get('next','')
if next:
 do something
```

I had gone through the official django documentation but didn't get much about securing the request.GET and META methods.
[Security doc for django.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/security/)

Comment: Why do you need GET in the first place? If you do any requests that modify data POST should be your choice, except you have a very special reason...

Answer (score 1):

That's only an XSS attack vector if you then dump the value of `next` directly to the template or redirect to it without checking.

For redirection, Django's built-in login form checks you're not redirecting to a different host - see [the code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L48).

For scripting attacks, Django will always autoescape any code, so `<script>` will be converted to `&lt;script&gt;`. You just need to be sure you don't turn autoescaping off or mark the variable as safe.